# Transfer learning for ConvLstm ucf101 to hmdb51

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I have trained my cnn-lstm on ucf 101 dataset. Now I want to train it on hmdb-51 dataset only on the last Dense layer a using pretained ucf-101 model weight for the rest of the layers.
How can I do that??

Comment: Can you explain what you already tried?

Comment: You can train with one dataset using model.pop() to remove the last layer and replace it with the target of the new dataset and train again.

Comment: Furthermore, I agree with @luistm that you should add more info and explain also what you have done already.

Comment: i have trained my model ucf 101 dataset
now i need to train last layer on hmdb51

Answer (score 2):

What can be done is to train your model with your source `dataset A` which contains L target output layers. Having trained your weights, you could load that weights remove the last layer using, for example, Keras `model.pop()` function and train your last layer with the new target. The following code is not tested, but you need to follow the logic:

```
model = Model_A()
model.compile(....)
model.fit(X_train_A, y_train_A, nb_epoch=..., batch_size=...,...)
# you load model_A which is defined for your dataset A and then you perform fit with the data from dataset A.
model.pop()
model.add(Dense(nb_classes_dataset_B))
# then proceed with model.fit() for dataset B
```